# How to integration test react-select multi select drop down menu using mocha, node, and selenium?

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, react-select

I am using `react-select V2` in my code and using the multi-select, my component looks as follows:

```
 <Select 
      isMulti 
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
      options={ this.getTransformedOptions() }
      components={{ Placeholder, DropdownIndicator }}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholderText}
      onChange={this.props.onChange('multi')}
 />
```

I use mocha, node, selenium, and chrome driver to create the integration tests for my app, so for this page, I would like to simply test opening the drop down menu, selecting some options, removing some options, etc.

If I pass `menuIsOpen={true}` to the component, I can easily click on the element with the following command:

`driver.findElement(By.css('.select__menu div[id="react-select-2-option-0"]')).click();`

However, I am still not able to click open the menu programmatically. Does anyone know how I can do this with a similar command as above?

Comment: Post the rendered HTML. That's what Selenium will interact with.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using the selenium `actions` and `mouseDown` method as follows:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('div.select__dropdown-indicator')), TEST_TIMEOUT);
currentElement = driver.findElement(By.css("div.select__dropdown-indicator"));
driver.actions().mouseDown(currentElement).click().perform(); // expand drop down menu
currentElement = driver.findElement(By.className("select__input"));
driver.actions().mouseDown(currentElement).click().perform();
driver.findElement(By.css('.select__menu div[id="react-select-2-option-0"]')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To open the menu you should target is dropdown icon.

Using xPath it looks like:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'here__your__className')]//div[contains(@class, 'your__prefix__indicators')]
```

Using css:

```
driver.findElement(By.css('.your__prefix__indicators')).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @Laura, question, how do I find which is my `your__prefix__indicators`? If I look for the dropdown icon, like you suggest, I get to a `div` with classes `css-16pqwjk-indicatorContainer select__indicator select__dropdown-indicator`, but when I try to `click()` on this element, it does not expand the menu options. I also tried the parent div, with class `select__indicators` and that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: @thehme could improve your example because I do not have any issue performing the code above so I suspect it's specific to your use case.